# How to echo auto increment row number base on number of database rows in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, auto-increment

I have a table with 7 rows.
i want to show a auto number in index base on number of my database rows
first I get:

`$data['total'] = $this->db->counts_all('posts')`

In controller then pass it to index and in index

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>No.</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
        $counter = 0;
        while($counter < $total){
        $counter++;
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <?php
            echo $counter;
            }
            ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

But it goes to a loop of rows from 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ,7 in 7 times.
How to fix and loop just on. tkx

Comment: `$this->db->counts_all('posts');` is just number `7`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $total; $i++) {
    // echo $i
}
```

*Edit after more detailes:*

You don't need while or for loops. Just set generating keys in foreach loop. Since it is zero-based, echo it like `$key + 1` and you'll get the natural order:

```
<tbody>
<?php foreach ($posts as $key => $post): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $key + 1; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Yes it is true but my code is:
`<tbody>`
`<?php foreach ($posts as $post) : ?>`
**** Here I put my code ****
`<?php for ($i = 1; $i <= $total; $i++) : ?>`
`<tr>`
`<td></td>`

Comment: Feel free to vote up and/or accept the answer. Happy coding.